# UITableView, how to adjust the size of its header and footer?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiwebview

In auto-layout design, I choose universal size(600x600), and I drag a UITableView into the viewController within storyboard, this tableView occupy the whole horizontal space, and has 550 height. 
I want to add a UIWebView (to load a local static html file.) as footer to the tableView, but after I add it, the webView can't show correctly( Just like webView has more horizontal space) .

Its my code here:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [self loadHtml];
}
- (void) loadHtml {

  float height = 500; //maybe more , up to content of html
  _webview = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width , height)];
  ...
 // load html fille content as html
 [ _webview loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
 [self.table setTableFooterView: _webview];
}
```

I debug the size of _webview, and found its width always is 600, even I change its value when init. How did I do.
When use auto layout, that means we should not use fixed value, but how did init an UIView?

**NOTE** It's my fault, I do not add constraints for tableView.

Comment: So you mean you would like the web view to resize to its content height and then set as the footer?

Comment: yes, that's my want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this in code. When the table view is loaded create a web view and set the frame (only the width being the same as the table view really matters). Then, load the web view content and wait for the delegate to be told it's complete. Now you can get the content size of the web views scroll view and update the frame, then add as the footer view.

Comment: In webViewDidFinishLoad, and I check the size of my table, its (600x550) at this time, maybe my html is local and loading so quick.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to add UIWebView as UITableView's footer.
In order to change the height size of UITableView's footer you probably want to overwrite the delegate method:

`objc
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section`

In addition to this, in the case you want to change the view size based on the content of webView, you'd want to try like

`objc
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    JSKOriginalWebView *webview = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width , height)];
    [webview loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
    return [webview heightForContent];
}`

JSKOriginalWebView is the original webview and heightForContent returns height for the content. In this way you can integrate with auto layout.

Comment: No , I want to add footer for table, not section.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the frame property of the tableFooterView same as a Added WebView to It.